# 51Degree.mobi and Razor

Tags: android, iphone, asp.net-mvc, razor, 51degrees

I create a ASP.net MVC 4 project by using Visual Studio 2010 IDE.
I want to make sure that my web application could run at Desktop PC as well as Mobile Browsers which is not the same sizes and properties.

After learning from [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3/), I found that I need to use [51Degree](http://51degrees.mobi/) when it comes to android based opera browsers detection.

But unfortunately, when i use nuget command

```
Install-Package 51Degrees.mobi
```

The downloaded data is not like I already expected.
Below is my current project situation after I downloaded by using nuget Command,

```
01.)51Degrees.mobi.config   [found]
02.)AppStart_51Degrees.cs   [not found]
03.)FiftyOne.Foundation.dll [found]
04.)~/App_Data/wurfl.xml.gz [not found] 
05.)~/Mobile                [found]   
06.)<redirect> element inside <fiftyOne>  
           [not found at web.config]
           [found at 51Degrees.mobi.config]
```

Could anyone please give me any suggestion or any reference links which using `Razor and 51Degree.mobi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

51Degrees.mobi has been updated to version 2 since the blog post you refer to was written. The files you mention are no longer required. I suggest you look at [this blog post](http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Blogs/tabid/212/EntryId/26/51Degrees-mobi-and-MVC4.aspx) for guidance on MVC4 mobile detection.